# Trying to allow users to upload files; File comes in "null" (ASP.Net / MVC / C#)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, ajax.beginform

I have a page with a form that allows users to select an image (`DefectImage` in my model) to upload. Unfortunately, in the controller, `DefectImage` comes in as "null", even though I'm definitely selecting a file. The textbox even shows the file name before I hit Submit.

**Model**

```
public class CreateReportViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Electrode Image")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase DefectImage { get; set; }

}
```

**View**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("createreport", "wip", new { id = ViewBag.Id, enctype = "multipart/form-data" }, ajaxOpts, new { @id = "form-create" }))
{

    <div class="form-group row">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "col-sm-4 text-sm-right" })
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm" })
            <p>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Description)
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="form-group row">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DefectImage, new { @class = "col-sm-4 text-sm-right" })
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DefectImage, new { type = "file", @class = "form-control form-control-sm" })
        <p>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DefectImage)
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="row form-group-buttons">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4">
            <button id="btn-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateReport(CreateReportViewModel model)
{
    GenericResultModel jsonResponse = new GenericResultModel();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        byte[] uploadedImage = new byte[model.DefectImage.InputStream.Length];
        model.DefectImage.InputStream.Read(uploadedImage, 0, uploadedImage.Length);

        try
        {
            // send file to DB
            jsonResponse.IsOK = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            // Exception
            jsonResponse.IsOK = false;
        }
    }
    return Json(jsonResponse, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

When I step through, `ModelState.IsValid` in the controller is evaluating to `false` because my file (which is required) is `null` for some reason. `Description` comes through just fine, but not `DefectImage`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You've got your `enctype` in the wrong place - you've put it in the route values, but it's an HTML attribute.

So:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("createreport", "wip",
    new { id = ViewBag.Id, enctype = "multipart/form-data" },
    ajaxOpts,
    new { @id = "form-create" }))
```

Should be:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("createreport", "wip",
    new { id = ViewBag.Id },
    ajaxOpts,
    new { @id = "form-create", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Answer (score 0):

@Johnny is right, but that's only part of the issue. Files must submitted in a very particular way with AJAX, and the AJAX helpers do not support this. Also, you'll need to bear in mind that AJAX uploads, in general, are only supported in modern browsers, meaning IE 9 and under need not apply.

To do an AJAX upload, you need to do the following:

```
document.getElementById('MyForm').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = this;

    var formData = FormData(form);

    var files = document.getElementById('MyFileInput').files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
    {
        formData.append('files[]', files[i], files[i].name);
    }

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', form.action, true);
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
          // File(s) uploaded.
        } else {
          alert('An error occurred!');
        }
    };
    xhr.send(formData);
});
```